# Query for Stack Overflow users information using their OpenID?

Tags: support, reputation, openid, api

Is it possible to confirm someone as a user of Stack Overflow with a certain rep level if they authenticate with your site using OpenID?

E.g.

Bob logs into my codersarecool.com site with his bob.openid.com OpenID.

I then query Stack Overflow to get some info on bob.openid.com using bob.openid.com and not his Stack Overflow user id (as I don't know this, and can't prove its his if he supplies it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

However, you *can* confirm their Stack Overflow user Id by having them authenticate with the [OAuth flow](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) of the API and then calling the [`/me` method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me).